# Changing Background Video in React on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I have a Header component with a few links, I would like the background video to change depending on which link I am hovering over.

Inside the Header component, I have a BackgroundVideo component receiving props to dynamically change the source. However, the background still is not changing.

Here is my Header component code:

```
export default function Header() {
  const [sourceVid, setSourceVid] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <BackgroundVideo source={sourceVid} />
      <div className="header">
        <h1 onMouseEnter={()=>setSourceVid('clouds')}>
          <a href="#">CLOUDS</a>
        </h1>
         <h1 onMouseEnter={()=>setSourceVid('marble')}>
          <a href="#">MARBLE</a>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my BackgroundVideo component:

```
import React from 'react';
import clouds from './assets/clouds.mp4';
import marble from './assets/marble.mp4';

import './styles/BackgroundVideo.scss';

export default function BackgroundVideo({ sourceVid }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <video className="clouds" autoPlay muted loop>
        <source type="video/mp4" src={sourceVid} />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think what is happening is that it is being passed a string, instead of a reference to the imported videos. But I'm not sure how to reconcile that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, as you point out, that you're passing a string as the `source` prop, and then just passing that to the `src` attribute of your `source` element, rather than passing the actual imported video (variable with the same name as the content of the string).

(Also could be that the name of the prop in `BackgroundVideo` is `sourceVid`, but when used in `Header`, the prop is called `source`).

The simplest way I can think to fix this would be to create a small function for handling getting the video asset from a string name. For example:

```js
function getSourceVid(sourceVidName) {
  switch (sourceVidName) {
    case "clouds":
      return clouds;
    case "marble":
      return marble;
    default:
      return null; // or some default video
  }
}
```

Then just make use of this in your `BackgroundVideo` component, like so:

```js
export default function BackgroundVideo({ sourceVidName }) { // note renamed prop here
  const sourceVid = getSourceVid(sourceVidName);

  return (
    <div>
      <video className="clouds" autoPlay muted loop>
        <source type="video/mp4" src={sourceVid} />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```